# Stop AHK from messing with dead keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I use a spanish keyboard layout, so normally I press <kbd>´</kbd> (nothing appears on the screen), then <kbd>a</kbd>, to make na `á`. That's the normal behaviour, and one that I'm willing to keep.

When I ran a AHK script, instead of getting `´a`, I get: `´´a`. I  found this happens when the creating hotstrings, like `:*:btw::by the way`.

Is there anyway to stop AHK from interfering, or if not, recreating the functionality so I'm not forced into stopping the script? (pausing it doesn't work either).

With this simple script, my dead keys stop working:

```
:*:btw:by the way
; or
::btw:by the way
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me exactly what is happening here (i.e. how ex. `´´a` is being produced by your `.ahk` script) but this [AutoHotkey forum post](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/16920-how-to-enter-basic-spanish-accented-characters/) might have some relevant information and links.

Comment: You may also want to [edit] your question to add some details regarding e.g. your exact `.ahk` script, specific steps you are taking which create the relevant problem, etc. to add further clarity regarding your issue.

Comment: I added a simple script that interferes with my dead keys. That link didn't work, because I already use a keyboard and an equivalent layout in my OS that manage them.